# How to clear all configurations on RMAN

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

How can I clear all configurations listed with the command `show all` on RMAN to default? I just found how to clear one unique configuration for exemple: `CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK clear`

Comment: The way you have cleared the configuration is correct and there is no other way to clear all the configurations at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same way:  CONFIGURE option_name CLEAR;
There is no 'clear all'.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RCMRF/rcmsynta009.htm#RCMRF113